# EXCEL VLOOKUP to other workbook

Tags: excel, vlookup, worksheet

i keep trying and trying but nothing always N/A
photo added.
i tried to put e:\onedrive\ubuy
but still didn't work.
i need that the left workbook in cell C2 will be vlookup of cell A2 in the right workbook from D2 cell
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLirN.png)l 2 to AA cell 400.
and will show me in C2 the value at AA.
Ty :[

command that i did
=VLOOKUP(A2,'[מחירון פריטים - עסקית.xlsx]xl_PriceList'!$D$2:$AA$375,23,FALSE)

Comment: Can you try to rephrase your question (preferrably in an edit)? I'm not quite sure what it is you're asking, and the formatting makes it very difficult to read.

Comment: im trying to seek a number that in excel 1 in excel 2

Comment: pnuts D2 its a column of numbers.

Comment: HAHA number storage as text!
worked thanks!

Comment: but when im saving the excel is auto put it as test how can i auto make it as number?

Comment: when im to F2 on the cell and then enter is fix the problem but why it happened from the beggining?

Comment: im import the excel from a programe that do that =\ should i just make my excale serach for test and not number?

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your data, you can edit your formula to this:

```
=VLOOKUP(TEXT(A2, "@"),'[מחירון פריטים - עסקית.xlsx]xl_PriceList'!$D$2:$AA$375,23,FALSE)
```

The `text(A2, "@")` converts your lookup value to text format (same as the data you're searching) on the fly, so you don't need to edit your data.